# Why is better to use filter_input()?

Tags: php, security, filter

This should be a elementary question but why is better to use something like this:

```
$pwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pwd');
```

Instead of just:

```
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
```

PS: I understand that the filter extension can be used with more arguments to provide an additional level of sanitization.

Comment: The question has more votes than the accepted answer. Interesting ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not.  `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` and `$_REQUEST` are [filtered with default filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.configuration.php). `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pwd')` without additional parameters also uses the default filter. So there is no difference at all.

Comment: Was looking around for `filter_input` vs. `htmlspecialchars` and noticed this appears to be outdated.  Most PHP configurations do not filter this data anymore, the link you post even has the default configuration value set as "unsafe_raw"

Comment: @Charles: in both cases data passes through the default filter. That default now happens to be `"unsafe_raw"`, but that doesn't change the fact that using `filter_input` without `filter` parameter does not give you any additional level of security.

Comment: On my Server there is a difference, when magic_quotes_gpc is turned on. The filtered one does not includeslashe, while referencing it with $_POST has. So far I copuldn't figure out why,... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533122/when-does-filter-input-remove-slashes-of-post-variables-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Any data which is sent from the client (such as POST data) should be sanitized and escaped (and even better, sanity-checked) to ensure that it isn't going to kill your website.

[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) are the two largest threats for failing to sanitize your user-sent data.

Comment: Is filter_input() still necessary if you're using parameterized queries and htmlspecialchars() before you print any user-supplied data?

Comment: filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pwd'); (without any other argument still sanitizes the value?

Comment: @Ben: generally you're right, but that's not an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is not better.

Please see docs on filter_input 
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.filter-input.php

and click the "Types of Filters" link.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

I have only ever used the integer filter ...

```
$user_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$user = abs($user_id); // To get rid of any +/-
```