# When does filter_input() remove slashes of POST variables?

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

I created a small PHP-script, that runs on a server with PHP 5.2.17 and the `magic_quotes_gpc` directive enabled.

I have no write-access to the php.ini file, and I'd like to remove all slashes from user inputs.

This should work even if the `magic_quotes_gpc` directive is turned off (for example when moving the scripts to another server).

It should also work recursively when arrays are submitted by the user.
I prefer using a built in-function.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HP</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="magic.php">
<input type="text" value="te\\&quot;st" name="test1">
<input type="text" value="te\\&quot;st" name="test2[tw&quot;o]">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php

echo "<pre>";
echo "magic_quotes: ".get_magic_quotes_gpc()."\n";
echo "<hr>test1";
echo "filter_input: ".filter_input(INPUT_POST, "test1")."\n";
echo "POST:         ".$_POST['test1']."\n";

echo "<hr>test2 (filter)";
print_r(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST))."\n";

echo "<hr>test2 (post)";
print_r($_POST)."\n";

echo "</pre>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Which gives the following result on my server:

```
magic_quotes: 1

filter_input: te\\"st
POST:         te\\\\\"st

test2 (filter)Array
(
    [test1] => te\\"st
    [test2] => Array
        (
            [tw\"o] => te\\"st
        )

)

test2 (post)Array
(
    [test1] => te\\\\\"st
    [test2] => Array
        (
            [tw\"o] => te\\\\\"st
        )

)
```

It seems that except for the array keys the slashes are removed.

Or are the slashes never added? (`filter_input()` and `filter_input_array()` might ignore the `magic_quotes_gpc` directive, since it is deprecated; but I could not find a reference for that)

Is the behaviour for removing/not setting the slashes of `filter_input()` and `filter_input_array()` somehow dependent on system-parameters?
I don't understand the warning [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

Answer (score 3):

I've been unsuccessful in finding it in official documentation, but the `filter_input()` function operates on the raw data, and is unaffected by `magic_quotes` settings. The sanitize filter, `FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES`, will put them in if you need them.

It's been a boon for me personally, because I'm working in a legacy system that has `magic_quotes` turned on. By using the `filter_input()` function I can use the values without having to strip slashes before binding them in `PDO`.

These articles talk about it:
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?590848-Filter_input-magic-quotes
https://weston.ruter.net/2013/10/22/revelations-about-filter_input/
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#99124

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something along the following lines for normalizing input data against the magic_quotes setting.

```
function deslash (array $data)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $val)
    {
        $data [$key] = is_array ($val)? deslash ($val): stripslashes ($val);
    }
    return $data;
}

if ((!empty ($_POST)) && (get_magic_quotes_gpc ()))
{
    $posted = deslash ($_POST);
}
```

Comment: I use a similar thing at the moment, but if filter_input() and filter_input_array() do the things I need, I'd prefer not writing an extra recursive function for that. But I have no idea WHY filter_input is doing the things it does. Tha would be great to know.