# Form and PHP in one file

Tags: php, html, forms

I am just tottaly newbie with PHP and I am now learning how to combine PHP with HTML form. I wanted it in one file, so I tried this:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['button'])){ //check if form was submitted
  $pohlavie = $_POST['gender']; //get input text
  $plat = $_POST['salary']; //get input text
  $plat = "Your gender is ".$pohlavie." and your salary is ".$plat;
}    
?>

<center><h1>TAXES</h1></center>
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
Salary: <input type="number" name="salary"><br>
<button type="submit" name="button" formmethod="post">Calculate DPH</button>
</form>
```

Unfortunately, it's literally doing nothing after submitting. Can you please help me a little bit?

Comment: So, what do you want to do? print the result?

Comment: You are not doing anything with your variables. You need to echo them.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot echo! I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying the using the following line in place of your current form line:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">`
```

Comment: The action to `PHP_SELF` is not needed as the submit will send a HTTP POST request to the current destination. This doesn't fix OPs "problem" as they forgot to `echo` the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $plat = "Your gender is ".$pohlavie." and your salary is ".$plat;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. *Explain* what you did.

Answer (score 1):

here is:

```
 <?php    
 if(isset($_POST['button'])){ //check if form was submitted
 $pohlavie = $_POST['gender']; //get input text
 $plat = $_POST['salary']; //get input text
 echo "Your gender is ".$pohlavie." and your salary is ".$plat;
 }    
 ?>

<center><h1>TAXES</h1></center>
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
Salary: <input type="number" name="salary"><br>
<button type="submit" name="button" formmethod="post">Calculate DPH</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. *Explain* what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Always follow best coding practices and use recommended features. Here the code with little modifications:

```
<?php
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "button")) { //check if form was submitted
  $pohlavie = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gender'); //get input text
  $salary = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'salary'); 
  echo $plat = "Your gender is ".$pohlavie." and your salary is ".$salary;
}    
?>

<center><h1>TAXES</h1></center>
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
Salary: <input type="number" name="salary"><br>
<button type="submit" name="button" formmethod="post">Calculate DPH</button>
</form>
```

You can also use different type of sanitize filters based on your needs. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Also see this post to get more knowledge regarding filter_input:
[When to use filter_input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102796/when-to-use-filter-input)

Hope it will help you to learn and follow best practices in PHP.